# Insert abbreviation and open completion

Tags: autocompletion, abbreviations

I sometimes add abbreviations for local files or projects.

For example having:

```
PREFIX_FOO
PREFIX_BAR
PREFIX_BAZ
```

Instead of typing `PREFIX_` I map it to something, for example `PP` or `P1`, `P2`, ... etc.

```
:iab PP PREFIX_
```

How can I open completion for the `PREFIX_` in addition to the abbreviation swap when using `abbr<SPACE>`?

PS: Using `abbr<C-]>` would make it simpler, but rather type `abbr<SPACE>` over `abbr<C-AltGr-9>` which is the case on my keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `<C-n>` to the mapping.
2. Trim away the added space. Has to be done *after* completion keys.

```
:iab PP PREFIX_<C-n><C-p><C-R>=trim(getcharstr(0))<CR>

" or to keep first selected:

:iab PP PREFIX_<C-n><C-R>=trim(getcharstr(0))<CR>
```

The `trim(getcharstr(0))` is a shorter version of `Eatchar()` as described in `:h abbreviations`

Should work for both `ABR<SPACE>` and `ABR<C-]>`